# Removing duplicate emails through command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, command

I have two lists of emails in text files:

emails.txt - people who are subscribed to my newsletter
blacklist.txt - people who have unsubscribed

I'm in the process of changing newsletter softwares right now.  Obviously I don't want to email people who have decided to unsubscribe.  Is there a way through command line to check if any of the emails listed in blacklist.txt are currently in my emails.txt file and if they are to remove them?

Note:  all emails are on a separate line.  I know how to remove duplicates by using `sort` and `uniq` but that still leaves at least one of them in the file.  I need the emails contained in blacklist.txt to be completed removed from emails.txt and for the cleaned email list to be output to clean.txt

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
grep -vwF -f blacklist.txt emails.txt
```

It will just show lines from  `emails.txt` that are not in `blacklist.txt`.

- `grep -v` inverts the results found.
- `grep -f` gets a file as the pattern to compare
- `grep -w` compares full words
- `grep -F` match exact string

Comment: nice thought, but you may need the `-F` and `-w` check this two emails `fedorqui.good@foo.com` and `fedorqui_good@foo.com` without `-F` and `-w` they will be matched each other.

Comment: Mmm it sounds interesting. I did not know about `-F` functionality. Updated answer, thanks very much @Kent!

Answer (score 1):

`grep -v` (with **`-F and -w`**) is one way to go. you can still try `comm`..

also `awk` can do it:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}!a[$0]' black.txt email.txt
```